# Symfony 2 - switching from app_dev to app

Tags: php, symfony

i didnt understand how assets:install works..

When i run php app/console assets:install web it copy these bundles.

```
Installing assets for Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle into web/bundles/framework
Installing assets for Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle into web/bundles/sensiodistribution
```

I want to copy my project to app.php, the project is in /src/Dproc/..bundles..

How should i do that?

Comment: `app.php` is just a file, It makes no sense to copy something into a file.

Comment: yes, how i can switch enviorment?

Comment: you just start requesting `app.php` not `app_dev.php`

Comment: yes, but my code works on app_dev.php, when i'm opening app.php - it's not showing the whole code, i guess i need to copy my project to app enviorment or?

Comment: it should work. If it doesn't - you've made something wrong

Comment: when i cleared cache, the code works properly. So when i do changes in dev, i need to clear cache of prod?

Comment: And still i couldnt use external css.. I have base.html.twig in app/resources/views where is  <link href="{{ asset('/css/base.css') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> - the css file is in src/Dproc/MainBundle/Resources/views/Dproc/views/css/base.css - so how should my link look like?

Comment: Did you try to do: php app/console assets:install web --env=prod ?

Comment: I did - Installing assets for Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle into web/bundles/framework

Answer (score 0):

Switching to the prod environment:

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

Comment: How clearing cache is related to "switching"? If you haven't used it yet - presumably it will be empty anyway.

Comment: `cache:clear` doesn't **just** clear cache. It clears the old one (if it exists) and warms up new one.

Comment: I don't know why, I have only suggestions they may be wrong.. but I always used that for switching environments and it worked.

Comment: So when i do changes in dev enviorment, i need to clear production cache to get it work properly on production enviorment?

Comment: Exactly, dev environment will automatically detect changes and warmup cache again, but all those features are turned off in production so you will have to do it manually. Generally, you should just develop in dev and when you're ready to deploy some version of your application, switch to production and you're done.